# Do you need to specify the "defaults" option in fstab?

Tags: fstab, options

The [Arch Wiki on `fstab`](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Fstab) specifies the options of `/` to be `defaults,noatime`, but on my installation the default `fstab` is created with the options of `rw,relatime`. The [Arch Wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Fstab#atime_options) covers the `atime` issues. What I am curious about is the `defaults` option. The `man` page for `mount` says:

> defaults
>
> Use the default options: rw, suid, dev, exec, auto, nouser, and async.
>
> Note that the real set of all default mount options depends on kernel and filesystem type.  See the beginning of this section for more details.

Are the default options used only if the `defaults` option is provided or are they used in all cases? Do I need `defaults` in my `fstab`?

Comment: you have to specify defaults as least as place holder, however should you specify anything else (like `ro` or `nosuid`), you can forget default.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

You only need `defaults` if the field would otherwise be empty.

You can leave out the options field altogether if it's empty, unless the 5th or 6th fields are present. Field 5 is the dump frequency, rarely used nowadays. Field 6 `fsck` order, should be 1 for `/`, 2 for other filesystems mounted on boot and 0 otherwise. Fields 5 and 6 can be omitted if their value is 0, except that field 5 needs to be present if field 6 is.

Thus `defaults` is necessary in

```
/dev/foo /foo somefs defaults 0 1
```

(though you can use some other option like `rw` or `ro` instead)

But it can be omitted when you specify another option.

eg: The mounts below have the same effect.

```
/dev/foo /foo somefs ro            0 1
/dev/foo /foo somefs defaults,ro   0 1
```

But these also have the same effect.

```
/dev/foo /foo somefs defaults      0 0
/dev/foo /foo somefs
```

Comment: While a 3-field `fstab` entry generally works, `leapp` (in-place upgrade utility for RHEL-based distributions) consideres it to be invalid and refuses to upgrade.