# differences between tmpfs in fstab

Tags: linux, rhel, fstab, tmpfs

we want to use tmpfs on `/var/work` folder

what is the differences between the following tmpfs in fstab

```
tmpfs  /var/work   tmpfs   size=4g   0 0
```

to this tmpfs in fstab

```
tmpfs /var/work tmpfs   defaults,size=4g    0 0
```

second - is it necessary to defined also the - `rw,nosuid,noatime,nodev` ?

```
tmpfs /var/work  tmpfs rw,nosuid,noatime,nodev,size=4G 0 0
```

Comment: Related: [Do you need to specify the “defaults” option in fstab?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/191405/do-you-need-to-specify-the-defaults-option-in-fstab)

Comment: what about - "tmpfs /var/work  tmpfs rw,nosuid,noatime,nodev,size=4G 0 0"

Comment: The `mount` man page states that `rw,suid,dev,exec,auto,nouser,async` are the defaults which also depend on the kernel and filesystem type.
So I'd guess you need `nosuid,noatime,nodev,size=4G`, but better verify the options with `mount`.