# /etc/fstab entries missing "defaults" option, is it implicit?

Tags: mount, fstab

My automatically generated `/etc/fstab` file has most of it's entries like so

```
# /dev/sda9
UUID=8de1f4d1-4620-49f0-aeaf-a499f7cb6c21   /home       ext4        rw,relatime 0 2
```

It's missing the `defaults` option. My system works fine, but I am not sure if:

1. Default values are implicitly set, if so, why is `rw` there? I can't see any notice that they are implicit in the man page.
2. My system is mis-configured and just happens to be running ok (for months) and I should insert the `defaults` option (maybe for `async`, etc).

My system is Arch with Systemd, maybe that is picking up the slack.

Comment: I use Ubuntu and have in my old notes: Since Hardy (or Intrepid), Ubuntu adds the relatime option by default.
relatime = relatime + defaults = relatime, rw, suid, dev, exec, auto, nouser and async  But cannot now find any info showing that. I use relatime for HDD partitions and noatime for SSD partitions. Old kernel info: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/17844/when-was-relatime-made-the-default My relatime only setting in fstab, shows as rw,relatime in mount.

Answer (score 0):

- This option is **not** implicit.
- `defaults` (may) mean different options for different filesystems.
- It's OK not to have it if you're not interested in the options it bestows.
- There are default (implicit) mount options depending on your kernel/distro. For Ubuntu it's `rw,relatime`.

From `man mount`:

```
       defaults
              Use the default options: rw, suid, dev, exec, auto, nouser, and async.

              Note that the real set of all default mount options depends on the kernel and filesystem type.
              See the beginning of this section for more details.
```

Comment: Is there a way to find what defaults were set by the kernel? Searching for "arch mount options" etc doesnt show any useful information. If the defaults are not implicit, how does my `/home` mount on boot (`auto`) or permit execution of binaries (`exec`)? `zcat /proc/config.gz` doesn't really show anything related to this, nor does `/proc/mount` (just mirrors `fstab`).

Comment: Related I guess https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/191405/do-you-need-to-specify-the-defaults-option-in-fstab seems to imply defaults are implicit.